# How to affect property of original object when setting one object equal to another object C#

Tags: c#, pointers, reference

Making a text game to practice coding and ran across a really weird issue. I searched on this but most people are trying to clone one object to another whereas I am trying to point Object B to Object A because I want to change the properties of the same object.

```
public Armor Player_Chest_Armor { get; set; }
public Armor Player_Head_Armor { get; set; }
public Armor Player_Legs_Armor { get; set; }
    public Weapon Player_Weapon { get; set; }
    public Spell Player_Spell { get; set; }
    public List<Consumable> Consumables { get; set; }
    public List<IEquipment> Inventory { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
public Player (string name) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Consumables = new List<Consumable>();
        this.Inventory = new List<IEquipment>();
        this.Inventory.Add(new Weapon("bronze sword", 22, 28, 25, 1.2, false));
        this.Inventory.Add(new Armor("bronze chestplate", Armor.ArmorSlot.Chest, 35, 10, 20, false));
        this.Inventory.Add(new Armor("bronze helmet", Armor.ArmorSlot.Head, 12, 3, 7, false));
        this.Inventory.Add(new Armor("bronze legplates", Armor.ArmorSlot.Legs, 20, 5, 10, false));
        this.Consumables.Add(new Consumable("minor health potion", 3, Consumable.PotionType.Health, 50));
        this.Consumables.Add(new Consumable("minor mana potion", 3, Consumable.PotionType.Mana, 50));
        this.Player_Spell = new Spell("Fireball", 50, 0, 1);
    }

    public void EquipInitialGear() {
        this.EquipWeapon(this.Inventory[0] as Weapon);
        this.EquipArmor(this.Inventory[1] as Armor);
        this.EquipArmor(this.Inventory[2] as Armor);
        this.EquipArmor(this.Inventory[3] as Armor);
    }
    public void DecreaseArmorDurability() {
        try {
            this.Player_Chest_Armor.DecreaseDurability();
        }
```

This is the relevant part of code from my player class. Player_ whatever is for stuff that the player has equipped, whether it's armor, weapons, etc. I'm using an IEquipment interface to connect both armor and weapon objects in one list since a player inventory should include everything. When the player is created, the EquipWeapon and EquipArmor method calls are setting those inventory index objects to the appropriate player armor/weapon slot. Code for that below and assuming for simplicity that there is no weapon already equipped so it goes straight to the this.Player_Weapon = weapon line.

```
    public void EquipWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        if (weapon.IsEquipped() == true) {
            Console.WriteLine("You have already equipped {0}.", weapon.GetName());
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (this.Player_Weapon.Equipped == true) {
                this.UnequipWeapon(this.Player_Weapon);
            }
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException) {}
        this.Player_Weapon = weapon;
        weapon.Equipped = true;
        Console.WriteLine("You have equipped {0}.", this.Player_Weapon.GetName());
    }
```

When I try to change the property value of say Player_Weapon, it changes for that object, but the object in inventory (which should be the same) has the original property value. Decrease durability does the following in the Weapon class:

```
    public void DecreaseDurability() {
        this.Durability -= 1;
    }
```

Every attack round, I have it call this method to decrease the weapon's durability by 1 out of a max of 100. In debugging mode, I can see where this.Player_Weapon.Durability goes from 100 to 99. However, if I go look at what should be the same object in inventory, it's durability is 100, which makes me think that it's creating a copy of the object instead of referencing the original object.

I'm convinced this is a pointer issue but I just can't see where the issue is. I want changes to the properties of Player_Weapon to also affect changes to the same object of that weapon in inventory that it should be pointing to.

Edited for clarity: Player, weapon and armor are all classes, not structs.

Comment: see `ref` keyword.

Comment: `Weapon` is a `class`, not a `struct`, right?

Comment: Yes, it's a class, so it should be by reference not value.

Comment: _"the simplified example worked for object_b referencing object_a"_ that's not quite right. "object_b" does not "reference object_a". You can have to variables, that hold a reference to the same object. But they do not "reference each other".

Comment: I cannot see anything obvious from that code. `Player.Player_Weapon` should reference the same instance of `Weapon` as `Player.Inventory[0]`, like you say. There must be something else, somewhere else.

Comment: Unrelated: I'd do a null-check or use Null-Object-Pattern instead of try/catch(NRE) with empty catch block. That smells a bit.

Comment: Oh oh oh ... wait a second. `Player_Weapon` is r/w, while it should be read-only. The only place that should be allowed to set the `Player_Weapon` property should be the `EquipWeapon` method. Make it `{get; private set;}` and see where it breaks.

Comment: Inventory is also public ... another "attack vector" ... You need to make sure that whenever the inventory item is replaced, you update the property. Maybe you shouldn't have a `Player_Weapon` property like this _at all_. Maybe just keep an index into the Inventory marking the item that _is_ the player's weapon. But I'm ahead of myself ...

Comment: I'll take a look at comments tonight after work but love the ideas. Will look into null check...I want to make code as clean as possible. I think your solution for just storing the index of the item instead of setting an object equal to another object sounds like a good fix. Just wish I knew what the problem was lol.

Answer (score 0):

It's the JSON save game file. The reason this bug was so insidious that I asked SO for help is that it works fine, but when I quit the game which creates an autosave in JSON, it stores the object data. However, Player_Weapon and any of the Player_Armor are class pointers to the item in inventory. This works fine so long as the program is running. Once the JSON is created, and the data is saved, it appears that the Player class instances are decoupled from the inventory. This is what is saved in the file:

```
"Player_Chest_Armor": {
    "Name": "bronze chestplate",
    "ArmorCategory": 1,
    "ItemValue": 35,
    "ArmorRating": 12,
    "Equipped": true,
    "Durability": 98
  },
  "Player_Head_Armor": {
    "Name": "bronze helmet",
    "ArmorCategory": 0,
    "ItemValue": 12,
    "ArmorRating": 6,
    "Equipped": true,
    "Durability": 98
  },
  "Player_Legs_Armor": {
    "Name": "bronze legplates",
    "ArmorCategory": 2,
    "ItemValue": 20,
    "ArmorRating": 8,
    "Equipped": true,
    "Durability": 98
  },
  "Player_Weapon": {
    "Name": "notched axe",
    "RegDamage": 16,
    "ItemValue": 10,
    "CritMultiplier": 1.2,
    "Equipped": true,
    "Durability": 98
  },
  "Player_Spell": {
    "Name": "Fireball",
    "ManaCost": 50,
    "Level": 1,
    "SpellCategory": 0,
    "FireOffense": {
      "BlastDamage": 30,
      "BurnDamage": 5,
      "BurnCurRounds": 3,
      "BurnMaxRounds": 3
    }
  },
  "Consumables": [
    {
      "Name": "minor health potion",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "ItemValue": 3,
      "Equipped": false,
      "PotionCategory": 0,
      "RestoreHealth": {
        "RestoreHealthAmt": 50
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "minor mana potion",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "ItemValue": 3,
      "Equipped": false,
      "PotionCategory": 1,
      "RestoreMana": {
        "RestoreManaAmt": 50
      }
    }
  ],
  "Inventory": [
    {
      "$type": "DungeonGame.Weapon, DungeonGame",
      "Name": "bronze sword",
      "RegDamage": 27,
      "ItemValue": 25,
      "CritMultiplier": 1.2,
      "Equipped": false,
      "Durability": 98
    },
    {
      "$type": "DungeonGame.Armor, DungeonGame",
      "Name": "bronze chestplate",
      "ArmorCategory": 1,
      "ItemValue": 35,
      "ArmorRating": 12,
      "Equipped": true,
      "Durability": 98
    },
    {
      "$type": "DungeonGame.Armor, DungeonGame",
      "Name": "bronze helmet",
      "ArmorCategory": 0,
      "ItemValue": 12,
      "ArmorRating": 6,
      "Equipped": true,
      "Durability": 98
    },
    {
      "$type": "DungeonGame.Armor, DungeonGame",
      "Name": "bronze legplates",
      "ArmorCategory": 2,
      "ItemValue": 20,
      "ArmorRating": 8,
      "Equipped": true,
      "Durability": 98
    },
    {
      "$type": "DungeonGame.Weapon, DungeonGame",
      "Name": "notched axe",
      "RegDamage": 16,
      "ItemValue": 10,
      "CritMultiplier": 1.2,
      "Equipped": true,
      "Durability": 98
    }
  ]
}
```

As indicated by the data in the save game file, there is no reference to the inventory item for the Player Weapon/Armor class data, so when the game reloads the data it decouples those objects from the original objects in inventory. Player Weapon/Armor is set to those values, but it is no longer referencing the instances of those classes in inventory, so it is creating a duplicate of the object.

The saved game code is creating a JSON file through serialization. From https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm, "By default Json.NET will serialize all objects it encounters **by value**".

The solution to preserving the reference seems to be declaring and initializing the json using the following code:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people, Formatting.Indented,
new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```

I wasn't using PreserveReferencesHandling before, which was causing this bug.